# Verb for forcing a situation in which you get more pain in order to avoid being stuck in lesser pain over a longer period of time

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

Is there a verb for forcing a situation in which you get more pain in order to avoid being stuck in lesser pain over a longer period of time?

Examples:

- When one forces himself/herself to vomit, for instance, in order to get the stomachache over with.
- When one forces a breakup with their partner in order to avoid a lengthy toxic relationship where both parties hurt each other, although the pain of a breakup is much worse, but still shorter.

Is there a verb/phrasal verb in English for that?

Comment: lesser pain? Or just less pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an idiom for this: **ripping off the band-aid.**

[Wiktionary defined it as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rip_off_the_band-aid)

> To perform a painful or unpleasant but necessary action quickly so as to minimize the pain or fear associated with it.

Comment: Yes ... I think that OP's stipulation of a verb or equivalent isn't going to be possible in an answer.

Comment: Well, "ripping off the Band-Aid" is a phrasal verb, "ripping" being the verb that starts it.

Comment: Another possible phrasal verb idiom is "biting the bullet," which idiomatically refers to people in olden times biting down on a bullet to suffer the great pain of some medical procedure, usually to bring a swift end to a lesser pain being suffered that'd continue to be suffered indefinitely or until its untreated cause resulted in death.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman It's not a phrasal verb in the usual sense, because it includes both a preposition and its complement.